# DIV element inside of LI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem showing a list with hidden divs. I use the `toggleSlide()` function from jQuery to show/hide the DIV elements whenever you click the LI element.

The problem comes when the DIV comes visible, as it gets over the rest of the elements instead of making a space between list elements to print it there.

Currently, this is the code I have:

```
elementList.append('<li class="element" onclick="toggleDetails(this);"><span class="elementName">' + elementsArray[i]["descMarca"] + ' ' + elementsArray[i]["descModelo"] + '</span>'
                            + '<div class="elementDetails hidden"><label for="marca">Marca:</label><span>' + elementsArray[i]["descMarca"] + '</span>'
                            + '<label for="modelo">Modelo:</label><span id="modelo">' + elementsArray[i]["descModelo"] + '</span>'
                            + '<label for="serialN">Licencia:</label><span id="serialN">' + elementsArray[i]["serialN"] + '</span>'
                            + '<label for="productN">Número de producto:</label><span id="productN">' + elementsArray[i]["productN"] + '</span>'
                            + '<label for="fecAlta">Fecha de alta:</label><span id="fecAlta">' + fecAlta + '</span>'
                            + '<label for="fecRenov">Fecha de renovación:</label><span id="fecRenov">' + fecRenov + '</span></div></li>');
elementList.css('display', 'block');
```

Being the required CSS this one:

```
.element {
    height: 5vh;
    line-height: 5vh;
    padding-left: 20px;
    vertical-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.elementDetails {
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 25%;
}
```

If I set `display: inline;` on the LI element, it works as intended. The issue comes when I want a vertical list, so it can't be done setting `display: inline;` property to each LI element.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you use the jsfiddle or the code editor here? and please also paste the html code

Comment: It's because you have a static `height` with your `li.element` items. I guess what you should do is there changing that `height` to `min-height`

Comment: Please to avoid such string creation in the future, its maintenance is a nightmare for other future developers (other than you). Please to try templating.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `display: block;` (instead of `display: inline;`) to the `li` element